# Unable to call Ajax function from php in server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having a problem to call the ajax function from the php after I clicked submit button to submit the form. Everything is working fine on Localhost, but when I transfer all of the php to FTP server, all the function can't work already.

In Localhost, I'm able to submit the file upload to filesystem which I name it "uploads" folder and then insert the data of the form into database with query. But when I try on the FTP server, where I also create a uploads folder to store the uploaded file, it can't work.

Anything I did wrong in my code or any configuration I need to set? Please point me out.

Here is my php code where I use to submit form :

schoolform.php

```
<!--Banner Item No 1 Start-->
<div class="box box-primary1"  id="no1" style="display:block;">
<div class="box-header">
<h3 class="box-title">Upload New Form Here <small>Only PDF</small></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="box-body">
     <form class="form" id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="box-body">
     <div class="form-group" >
     <label for="formName">Form Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="formName" id="formName" placeholder="Please Enter Name" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group" >
     <label for="formDescription">Form Description</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="formDescription" id="formDescription" placeholder="Please Enter Description" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
     <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file"  onChange="checkDisabled(testing);"><br>
     <p class="help-block">You file must not more than 1MB.     (Only PDF allowed)</p>
     </div> 

     <div class="checkbox">
     <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Add</button>        
     </div>
     </div><!-- /.box-body -->


     </form>         <!-- Date range -->
                     <!-- /.form group -->

                     <!-- Date and time range -->


                     <!-- /.form group -->

                     <!-- Date and time range -->
                     <!-- /.form group -->

                     </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                     </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Here is where I used to call the ajax function to insert the data:

```
//File and text upload with formDATA function
$("#form").submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);    
    $.ajax({
        url:'schoolFormItem.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
        if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        }).done(function () {
        //do something if you want when the post is successfully
        if(!alert('Form Had Successfully Inserted.')){document.getelementbyclassname('form').reset()}
                    });
            return false;

  });
```

Here is my query function to insert data into database and also filesystem :

```
<?php
include 'dbConnection.php';

global $dbLink;

    $path = "uploads/";

    $valid_formats = array("PDF", "pdf");
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
            $fName = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['formName']);
            $fDescription = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['formDescription']);

            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                    if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$actual_image_name))
                                {

                                //mysqli_query ($db,"INSERT INTO image VALUES('','hello','$actual_image_name')");
                                //mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
                                $query = "INSERT INTO schoolform_item (schoolform_name,schoolform_description,schoolform_data,schoolform_created) VALUES ('{$fName}','{$fDescription}','{$actual_image_name}', NOW())";
                                $result = $dbLink->query($query);
                                }
                            else
                                echo "failed";
                        }
                        else
                        echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                        
                        }
                        else
                        echo "Invalid file format..";   
                }

            else
                echo "Please select image..!";

            exit;
        }
?>
```

Did I miss any step or is any code is wrong? Because everything is working when I try on localhost with xammp. And it all become malfunction when put on the server.
Please guide me through this.

Comment: May be you are facing some permission issue on server. Please check your "uploads" folder permission.

Comment: @ajaykumartak I had enable all the permission already. But the problem now is the code can't call the ajax function which should come out a confirmation box for user to choose whether to click Ok or Cancel, then only it will be insert the data into database and upload the file into the folder.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?
If you are not using please use mozilla extension "Firebug".

Comment: Am I missing something? Where is the code that saves the file? All I see is the database code in your php

Comment: @DelightedD0D Hi, i had edited my code, sorry i paste the wrong code

Comment: @ajaykumartak Did u mean use javascript console?

Comment: So this isnt going to answer your specific question, but, are you married to using php and mysqli database for your project, or would you consider other data storage methods?

Comment: @DelightedD0D im using php and mysqli database, everything is working on my localhost, but it only can't function when i put on server. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to save images or PDFs? your code seems to be at odds with itself in that regard

Comment: Are you getting any kind of network errors in the console like maybe the path to `schoolFormItem.php` is not correct?

Comment: Nope, did not gettting any error on that

Answer (score 1):

The reason your confirm box never appears is actually because you have an error in `jquery.confirm.js` on line 147: `Uncaught ReferenceError: dataOptions is not defined` I see your using `jquery.confirm.js version 2.3.1`.

**In the official version the file ends like this:**

```
    /**
     * Globally definable rules
     */
    $.confirm.options = {
        text: "Are you sure?",
        title: "",
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "Cancel",
        post: false,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-primary"
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**In your copy, the file ends like this:**

```
     /**
     * Globally definable rules
     */
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.confirm.options = {
        confirm: $.noop,
        cancel: function (o) {},
        button: null,
        text: "Are you sure?",
        title: "Warning!",
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "Cancel",
        post: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-primary",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"
    }, dataOptions, options);
})(jQuery);
```

I would replace that bit of code iwth the original bit, or, better yet, grab a new copy of the file from [the jquery.confirm site](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm/releases/tag/2.3.1)

Comment: Hi, it still does not fix the issue. Everything is work on localhost.
Just when i put the code on server, it wont work. It does not call my Ajax function to call the schoolFormItem.php.

I had try to hardcode to call the schoolFormItem.php function, but it only insert data into my database and it does not upload the file into the "Uploads" folder in the server

Comment: Even when you only allow PDF file extensions, you are saving images locally?

Comment: Ok, wait, so the ajax code is never even fired? Lemme look at that again.. I still think you might need to allow the image file formats  in the meantime though...

Comment: Hi, yes i try to hardcode the call of schoolForm.php on the form , everything okay now on the server. But i want to try the ajax call, it just can't fire the ajax call to call the schoolForm.php file which is weird...

Comment: Is your page viewable online?

Comment: http://mica.com.my/cmstest/admin2/schoolform.php

This is my page, u can try it out...when i press submit button it won't come out the confirmation box and submit the file. Please upload only pdf file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72739/discussion-between-delightedd0d-and-marcus-tan).

Answer (score -1):

try `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax({})` and see. may be it's the cause, $.post is simplified. for more info http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

also try changing:

`var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);`

to:

`var formData = jQuery('#myform').serialize();`

try this code too:

`$("#form").submit(function(){if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {$.post('schoolFormItem',{data:$('#form').serialize()}, function(){$('#form #resetbtn').trigger('click');alert('success')})} else {alert('not posted');return false;}});`

at the top, have:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and wrap the code in:

`jQuery(function(){ //our code goes here })`

Comment: what is the different of $.ajax({}) and $.post()?

Comment: $.post is simplified $.ajax() @MarcusTan

Comment: not sure why my code can't fire the ajax function on the server

Comment: can it fire other jQuery functions?

Comment: Still no luck, the confirmation box still not pop out

Comment: can hangout on gplus and help you out?